# Angular not updating template on scope change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to update my template when the date in the input box changes.

My inputbox html is:

```
<div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
    <input type="text" id="id_date" class="form-control" ng-model="date" ng-change="sendPost()" value="{{ date }}"/>
</div>
```

My table template is:

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">term</td>
    <td ng-repeat="block in blocks">{{ data[block]['term'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ total['term'] }}</td>
</tr>
```

Finally my controller code is:

```
$scope.blocks = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
$scope.data = {'A': {'term': 0, 'term2': 7}, 'B': {'term': 2, 'term2': 3}, 'C': {'term': 5, 'term2': 14}};
$scope.total = {'term': 50, 'term2': 70};
$scope.date = "2016-01-01";

$scope.sendPost = function() {
    //console.log("working");
    var post_data = {"date": $scope.date};

    $http.post("/web_api", post_data).success(function (post_data, status) {
        $scope.data = post_data.data;
        $scope.total = post_data.total;
        console.log($scope.data);
        console.log($scope.total);
    }).error(function(response) {
        //console.log(response);
          $scope.error = 'ERROR';
      });
};
```

The console log is returning the required objects on the post request.

Comment: can you show the format of the  `post_data.data` you are getting from server?

Comment: The post_data.data format is {'A': {'term': 1, 'term2': 7}, 'B': {'term': 5, 'term2': 4}, 'C': {'term': 7, 'term2': 16}}

Comment: And you are sure it's json and not just a string with json in it? `console.log(typeof $scope.data);`

Comment: the type is **object**.

Comment: Is you template inside another `controller`? If so, you may want to use `$scope.$parent.*` instead of `$scope.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `.success` and `.error` are deprecated but still works. However, they give a raw data response.

You are trying to use `response.data` but there is no such thing.

```
// This is the old way. It still works, but you get a raw data response.
$http.post("/web_api", post_data).success(function (post_data, status) {
    $scope.data = post_data;  // <-- Fixed!
    $scope.total = post_data.total; // <-- There is no such thing.
    console.log($scope.data);
    console.log($scope.total);
}).error(function(response) {
    //console.log(response);
      $scope.error = 'ERROR';
  });
```

Better yet, use the new way:

```
$http.post(...).then( onSuccess, onError );
```

In `onSuccess` you can use $scope.data = post_data.data;

```
$http.post(...).then(function(post_data){
    $scope.data = post_data.data;
});
```

Other than that your code works fine. I tried it out thoroughly.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Comment: **post_data** contains *data* and *items* objects.

Comment: Then share how you inject your template. http://plnkr.co/edit/PJ9cHt4ctDwHrjOHIO20?p=preview  The code works so it's something you couldn't be bothered to show that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do some form of operation outside of **angularjs**, you need to let angular know to update itself.

try adding a $scope.$apply(); after

```
$scope.data = post_data.data;
$scope.total = post_data.total;
```

in your post request , it might work.

check more on [$scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

Comment: I am getting **$rootScope:inprog** error when I add $scope.$apply()

Comment: check on this link at the last part , "Diagnosing This Error" : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog

Comment: if(!$scope.$$phase) { $scope.$apply(); }  will prevent  the $rootScope:inprog  error

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your scope assignment block in a $timeout, this will send the operation to the end of the que. Like this:

`$http.post("/web_api", post_data).success(function (post_data, status) {
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.data = post_data.data;
            $scope.total = post_data.total;
            console.log($scope.data);
            console.log($scope.total);
        });
    }).error(function(response) {
        //console.log(response);
          $scope.error = 'ERROR';
    });`

Comment: doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your **$http promises** are different. Check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

**Try this:**

```
$http
.post('/web_api', post_data)
.then(function(response) {
    // success

    $scope.data = post_data.data;
    $scope.total = post_data.total;
    console.log($scope.data);
    console.log($scope.total);
}, function(response) {
    // error

    //console.log(response);
    $scope.error = 'ERROR';
})
.finally(function() {
    // finally.. like for disable loader ?! 
});
```

Comment: console is printing undefined